# How to delete an entry when I press a Button in Python Tkinter in a class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am a beginner. Can I ask you some help?

How can I clear an entry in Python tkinter. I can't clear it.
I tried Parameters such as END and 'END' But I can't clear the entry when I Press a button

Can you answer as soon as possible thanks. I am working in a project now

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
class TkinScreen:
    def main_screen_opening(self):
        self.screen = Tk()
        self.screen.geometry ('500x500')
        self.screen.title ('Rwooggle Account')
        my_heading1 = Label (text = 'Rwooggle.com', bg = 'blue', fg = 'yellow', font = ('Courier', 34, 'italic'), width = '500').pack()
        my_heading = Label (text = 'Login', bg = 'blue', fg = 'black', font = ('Courier', 24, 'bold'), width = '500').pack()

    def variables(self):
        self.username_var = StringVar()
        self.password_var = StringVar()
        self.age_var = IntVar()
        self.city_var = StringVar()

    def labels_entries(self):
        self.username_text = Label (text = 'Username*', font = ('Courier', 18)).pack()
        self.username_entry = Entry (textvariable = self.username_var, width = '30').pack()
        Label (text = "", width = '30').pack()
        
        self.password_text = Label (text = 'Password*', font = ('Courier', 18)).pack()
        self.password_entry = Entry (textvariable = self.password_var, width = '30').pack()
        Label (text = "", width = '30').pack()
        
        self.age_text = Label (text = 'Age', font = ('Courier', 18)).pack()
        self.age_entry = Entry (textvariable = self.age_var, width = '30').pack()
        Label (text = "", width = '30').pack()

        self.city_text = Label (text = 'Country', font = ('Courier', 18)).pack()
        self.city_entry = Entry (textvariable = self.city_var, width = '30').pack()
        Label (text = "", width = '30').pack()

    def button(self):
        log_in_but = Button (text = 'Log In', font = ('Courier', 20), command = self.button_command).pack()

    def button_command(self):
        print ('User Sucessfully Logged In')
        self.user_info = self.username_var.get()
        self.pass_info = self.password_var.get()
        self.pass_print = '*' * (len(self.pass_info))
        self.age_info = self.age_var.get()
        self.city_info = self.city_var.get().capitalize()

        txt_info = f"""\
    Username    :   {self.user_info}
    Password    :   {self.pass_print}
    Age         :   {self.age_info}
    Country     :   {self.city_info}
        """
        print (txt_info)

        self.username_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.password_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.age_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.city_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        

    def function(self):
        self.screen.mainloop()

tkint = TkinScreen ()
tkint.main_screen_opening()
tkint.variables()
tkint.labels_entries()
tkint.button()
tkint.function()
```

This is the error
User Sucessfully Logged In
Username    :   FFNNFD
Password    :   ******
Age         :   12
Country     :   Eggreg

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roger Geronimo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Roger Geronimo\Documents\Programming\SublimeText3\baf.py", line 53, in button_command
    self.username_entry.delete(0, 'end')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

I also tried the END Parameter

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: Nope. I want to change entry to a blank form

Comment: Read the dup thoroughly again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
self.username_entry = Entry (textvariable = self.username_var, width = '30').pack()
```

to

```
self.username_entry = Entry (textvariable = self.username_var, width = '30')
self.username_entry.pack()
```

I recommend to do this to all the entry boxes and then proceed as you normally do and it will solve the error :D

**Explanation:**

This is because `self.username_entry = Entry (....).pack()` returns `None`, ie, when you use `self.username_entry.delete(0,'end')` you are saying `Entry (....).pack().delete(0,'end')` which does not exist in the first place and since `self.username_entry = Entry (....).pack()` is None they give error, you received.

**Extra tip:**

- I recommend using a `master` argument on your widgets, like, `Entry(root)` or when you work with more windows, itll cause havoc.
- Instead of saying `print ('User Sucessfully Logged In')` you can use something like a `messagebox` with tkinter. [Here is how](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_messagebox.htm#:%7E:text=The%20tkMessageBox%20module%20is%20used,askokcancel%2C%20askyesno%2C%20and%20askretryignore.)

If you have any doubts, or errors, do let me know

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Whatever entry you want to clear , use `entry.set('')` in a function which will be called when button is clicked

Comment: Is that an empty string?

Comment: self.password_entry.set(' ')
self.age_entry.set(' ')
self.city_entry.set(' ')

Comment: just like that?

Comment: yeah it should work,your code also seems fine, kindly post you error as well, let me check

Comment: I used the same in my own project, I can help you out if you can post the error you are getting

Comment: ok. it shows NoneType Object has no attribute to set

Comment: 'Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roger Geronimo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Roger Geronimo\Documents\Programming\SublimeText3\baf.py", line 53, in button_command
    self.username_entry.set('')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set''

Comment: Well in that case is your `.get( )` working perfectly. Have you tried  printing your entry input, as I have also faced the same error , and variables used to access the input in entry are locally defined and cannot access the input in entry. I recommend trying to print whatever you give in entry box

Comment: @RogerGeronimo The error is because you are using `set` on `self.username_entry` instead it should be on `self.username_var` like `self.username_var.set('')` but this is not the correct way to do so, i recommend my answer for the proper way.